# Contacts: can one organisation be a 'child' of another?

Tags: contacts, relationships

Is there any way to make one organisation a part of another through a relationship? For example, we have a few NHS (National Health Service) teams among our contacts which we would like to put under one organisational umbrella.

I tried setting up a relationship the usual way but I couldn't add a relationship between two organisations, only an organisation and an individual.

At the moment we're using different addresses for each team as a workaround but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is:
- configure a new contact type 'NHS Team' based on organization
- cofigure a relationship type between organization and NHS team
The standard relationship type 'Child of' only works between Individuals, as you can see in the configuration of the relationship types.

If this is gobbledygook for you, I'd recommend reading this: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/relationships/

Comment: Thanks ErikH,

I meant 'Child' figuratively. I should have said 'Part of' instead.

I've set up a new relationship type and it works crackingly.

Cheers!

Comment: Glad it does, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think Dave Plummer is trained when he refers to the parent company and son company.

Comment: I would like to know about it, if that can be achieved.

Comment: An example of this Group of Financial Companies, which is the Parent company, then below it, are the other daughter companies, but that each one is granted their independent clients and their personalized invoices with their logo of each one, so , that is related to the group but that they handle their data separately within the same CiviCRM structures in a single and single installation.

Comment: I suggest you remove this 'Answer' and ask a separate Questino.